# Localization of multiple projects

Tags: wpf

Assume that I have multiple projects that I want to have localized.If for example I have repetitions of the resources inside the project strings such as for example I do not want to have "Customer" translated into 3 different languages 3 different times inside different resx files. What is the best way to handle such situations? Is the natural way to solve this redundancy to move the resource files that are shared inside a single resx file or is there a better approach already integrated inside WPF?

Comment: Primarily-opinion based? Are you serious>?

Comment: Yes, dead serious. There's no such thing as "best way". It depends on multiple factors and only you can decide which approach is the best for you and your current situation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's a general solution to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to have a dll just for your resources and reference it from all your projects is the way to go.